# Does the SharedPreference really have async API for writing in Android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've just read an article which is about `SharedPreferences` and it baffles me.
I've believed that SharedPreferences's `apply()` works asynchronously when it writes until now. You can see the reason [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#WriteSharedPreference).

But the article which is posted by Florina Muntenescu in [the Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/09/prefer-storing-data-with-jetpack.html?linkId=98693079) said
SharedPreferences has a synchronous API that can appear safe to call on the UI thread, but which actually does disk I/O operations. Furthermore, apply() blocks the UI thread on fsync().
There is only async API for reading changed values via listener.

So, What i want to ask are...

1. is `apply()` also synchronous method?
2. the official android document is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is apply() also synchronous method?

No. It returns immediately.

> the official android document is wrong?

Probably not. Florina is pretty good.

What Florina is saying in that blog post is that *a side-effect* of `apply()` is that at some point, the UI thread will be blocked due to the `fsync()` when the new preference values are written. Think of the side-effect as akin to pollution: the polluter (`apply()`) is not affected directly, but the pollution still has an impact, just a bit later on.

Comment: Thank you. 
What you said that `apply()` returns immediately is about in-memory. right? and also `apply()` works asynchronously when it writes(disk I/O operation). But it could make a pollution at some point because of the pending `fsync()`. `fsync()` will run anytime or anywhere in the future and it could make a ANR. Then how about we always call `apply()` on the worker thread or a coroutine which works on `Dispachers.IO`? I feel like it would be okay because it's not in Main(UI) thread...

Comment: @CodingBruceLee: " What you said that apply() returns immediately is about in-memory. right?" -- I am saying that it returns immediately, and its real work is done asynchronously. "Then how about we always call apply() on the worker thread or a coroutine which works on Dispachers.IO?" -- since `apply()` already uses a background thread, what you propose will not have an impact. My interpretation of Florina's comment is that the disk I/O is synchronized on something that can block the main application thread.